# Do we know any of the details about Worf's fights with the Kelvans?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-tos, worf

DS9 "Time's Orphan":

> WORF: No. I am a Klingon warrior and a Starfleet officer. I have
>   piloted starships through Dominion minefields. **I have stood in battle
>   against Kelvans twice my size.** I courted and won the heart of the
>   magnificent Jadzia Dax. If I can do these things, I can make this
>   child go to sleep.

The only occurrence of the Kelvans that I know of was in TOS "By Any Other Name." We learn in that episode that they have tentacles, are non-humanoid, take on humanoid form, etc. Worf says that they were twice his size, so I'm guessing that he fought them in their non-humanoid form.

Do we know when this fight occurred or any details about it other then what is in the episode "Time's Orphan?"

If there's any directors notes, writers notes, companion notes, manuals, etc. that make mention of it, that'd be helpful.

Comment: Nice question!  I recall this little speech that he gave, and I never thought about this.

Comment: Maybe Worf encountered one of the Kelvans that Captain Kirk and company first came across ("By Any Other Name"). A lone Klingon, presumably using a melee weapon or two, taking out extremely intelligent beings with 100 limbs seems utterly impossible. Worf was schooled by Commander MacDuff!

Answer (score 2):

Warning: Speculation alert!

Looking through Memory Alpha and Beta, there doesn't seem to be any more reference to this incident that what is said in the episode mentioned by the OP!

However, in the expanded universe, a fan-made story from the *Orion Press*, 'In Harm's Way', a Kelvan offensive was launched against the Gorn:

> In 2285, the Kelvans decimated the population of the Gorn homeworld
>   while making a second attempt to invade the Milky Way Galaxy. The
>   Federation formed ten task forces as a counteroffensive.

([Source](http://stexpanded.wikia.com/wiki/Kelvan))

Now, this is set well before Worf was even born!  However, I speculate that it could be possible that two of the Kelvans remaining from this offensive were the ones who Worf fought.  Just a possibility!

Answer (score -1):

Simple answer it was simply an exaggeration. Klingons exagerate so often its hard to break the habit

VOY: Prophecy

> TORRES: That's when they beamed aboard the Flyer, weapons firing. Tuvok and Neelix fought valiantly, but there were too many Hirogen. I had to face ten of their fiercest Hunters alone. 
>   PARIS: Is that how you remember it? 
>   TORRES: (underneath conversation) took them down two at a time, but they kept coming. 
>   NEELIX: **Exaggeration is part of Klingon custom**. She's doing great. 
>   TORRES: I had my phaser shot out of my hand, forcing me to take down the last Hunter in hand-to-hand combat. It was a glorious fight! 
>   KOHLAR: Your ancestors would be honoured.

Comment: -1 from me. Exaggerating stories may be a Klingon cultural trait, but Worf in particular would find lying about his exploits very dishonorable.

Comment: I respect your opinion, and thanks for explaining why you downvoted